# Lambda Authorizer and APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerContextOutput Problem

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, lambda-authorizer

In our C# Lambda Authorizer, we return an `APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse` (obviously). One of the properties of the `APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse` is the `Context` property which is of type `APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerContextOutput`. We want to use the `Context` property in the Authorizer Lambda to communicate with the "API Lambda" that the Authorizer sits in front of.

The problem is that even though `APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerContextOutput` extends `Dictionary<String, Object>` you cannot put `Object` values in the `Context`. You must have only `String` values in the `Dictionary`.

In the CloudWatch logs for the API Gateway, this is an error I see when I use `Object` values:

```
Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid JSON in response: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
```

Why does `APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerContextOutput` extend `Dictionary<String, Object>` if I cannot use real `Object` values?

Comment: if its c# why error is java.lang? you have to limit your json POST body string

Comment: It's probably a Java exception because AWS' code was written in Java. In other words, it's AWS' code that is dealing with the JSON. I can assure you, our code is C#.